# ACRA shows the notification then no dialog on notification click

Tags: android, acra

I have been working for a long with ACRA in silent mode.
Everything is fine and this is an awesome lib.

But today, I just wanted to use the notification method for a client.

I used it like this:

in MyApplication

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "****",
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.NOTIFICATION,
resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional, displayed as soon as the crash occurs, before collecting data which can take a few seconds
resNotifTickerText = R.string.crash_notif_ticker_text,
resNotifTitle = R.string.crash_notif_title,
resNotifText = R.string.crash_notif_text,
resNotifIcon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error, // optional. default is a warning sign
resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional. default is a warning sign
resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your application name
resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. when defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label
resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast // optional. displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.
)
```

And all the according strings in xml file.

In my Activity, I make it crash like this:

```
String i=null;
i.contains("kj");
```

Previously, the log was correctly sent to my google doc.

But now that I have notifications activated, the big problem is that I get the notification (Android 4.1.2) and when I click on it, nothing happen.

Logcat gives me this:

```
10-19 17:08:36.599: I/ACRA(12018): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
10-19 17:08:36.614: D/ACRA(12018): Retrieving logcat output...
10-19 17:08:36.700: D/dalvikvm(12018): GC_CONCURRENT freed 861K, 30% free 6778K/9603K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 33ms
10-19 17:08:36.700: D/dalvikvm(12018): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
10-19 17:08:36.700: D/ACRA(12018): Writing crash report file 1350659316000.stacktrace.
10-19 17:08:36.732: D/ACRA(12018): About to send status bar notification from #handleException
10-19 17:08:36.732: D/ACRA(12018): Creating Notification for 1350659316000.stacktrace

10-19 17:08:36.763: W/System.err(12018):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-19 17:08:36.771: D/ACRA(12018): Waiting for Toast + worker...
10-19 17:08:39.786: D/ACRA(12018): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Houps, I forgot:

```
<activity android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" />
```

Fixed now... :-D

Comment: Hi, I know this question is very old, but I have copied your code in this question exactly and im STILL not getting any sort of notification at all. Was there anything else you did?